# How to change the timezone offset in Java for a Date object?

Tags: java, datetime

I have a Date object that is getting the date from the database which is already in UTC, but the timezone offset gets converted based on the location where the application is running.

So if the database has date: `2019-09-06 00:00:00.000` and the application is running in LA, the Date object will have the offset of 7 and the output will look like this `2019-09-06T07:00Z`. Since the date is already in UTC, I want it to look like `2019-09-06T00:00Z` no matter where it is being run.

The Date class does not have a `setTimeZone()` method and the first thing that came to mind is to convert it to a String and hardcode `00:00Z` at the end, which isn't clean. Any ideas?

More info: The column has a type of DATETIME. DB: SQL Server.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Specify your database, its version, and the *exact* data type of the column.

Comment: Not only is the `Date` class poorly designed and long outdated. Also a `Date` cannot have a time zone. You are asking the impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a Date object that is getting the date from the database which is already in UTC,

Don’t.

The terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

You should be retrieving a moment from a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` by using [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

That value is likely to be in UTC. If you want to view that moment adjusted into a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> but the timezone offset gets converted based on the location where the application is running.

Be aware that while a `java.util.Date` is actually a moment in UTC, its `toString` method tells a lie. That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating its text. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature creates the illusion of a time zone being present inside the `Date`.

No such problem if you use the *java.time* classes only. There is no need to ever again use `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat`, or other such legacy classes.

> So if the database has date: 2019-09-06 00:00:00.000 and the application is running in LA, the Date object will have the offset of 7 and the output will look like this 2019-09-06T07:00Z

This part makes no sense to me.

Do you have the correct data types in your database? The `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` would be the *wrong* type to track a moment. This type has only a date and a time-of-day, but lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. This type cannot represent a specific point on the timeline.

Edit your Question to specify *exactly* what database and what data types are your columns.

At least try using the *java.time* to eliminate the confusion of `Date::toString` injecting an inappropriate time zone.

> The Date class does not have a setTimeZone() method

A `java.util.Date` is always in UTC, just a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Nothing more. (Actually there is more, a time zone buried deep, with no getter methods, that affects behavior of `equals` and such, but in irrelevant to our discussion here. This class is a bloody mess of bad design.)

> and the first thing that came to mind is to convert it to a String and hardcode 00:00Z at the end, which isn't clean. Any ideas?

No, you definitely should not play such games. You will only get deeper into trouble. Get your data types straight in your database, use only the *java.time* classes in Java, and your problems will be solved.

I cannot give further help since you did not provide enough details. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This topic has been addressed many many times already.

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` is a fixed moment in time. It can be *displayed* using different timezones, but it doesn't itself have a timezone.

A `DateFormat`, however, like `SimpleDateFormat`, can be set to use a specific timezone. Set the date format to use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` and you'll get the output you want.

By the way, starting with Java 8, there's a newer, improved date/time API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html