# Set timeZone in Date Java

Tags: java, date

Trying to set the timeZone in Date( I know Date is deprecated)

```
    LOG.error(modifiedDate + "Date in service"); //Mon Sep 21 06:15:00 CDT 2020
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String dateString = format.format(modifiedDate);
LOG.error(dateString + "  dateString"); //2020-09-21 06:15:00 -0500
Date date = format.parse(dateString);
LOG.error(date + "    date after parsing"); //Mon Sep 21 06:15:00 CDT
```

timeZone isn't changing after the parse, what am I missing?

Comment: *I know Date is deprecated* ==> Why are you using it? Do you have to?

Comment: yeah I have to as my object atm has to be Date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

Comment: See also: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: Then use the legacy compatibility methods: [`Date.toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) and [`Date.fromInstant(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) and perform conversions and calculations in between using `java.time`. Seriously, this sounds stupid but will be better, maybe even encouraging you to completely refrain from using `java.util.Date`...

Comment: I reopened this question, because I think neither of the two duplicate targets does a good job at explaining the underlying problem (i.e. that `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* timezone information).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297045/gregoriancalendar-class-in-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236052/get-gmt-time-in-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084820/date-time-conversion-based-on-the-timezone-java-groovy), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678030/calendar-returns-date-in-wrong-time-zone), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644208/java-calculate-month-end-date-based-on-timezone), –

Comment: – [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475409/getting-the-current-time-millis-from-device-and-converting-it-into-a-new-date-wi), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695243/how-do-i-set-timezone-on-a-specific-date), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070339/how-to-change-the-timezone-offset-in-java-for-a-date-object) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888534/how-to-set-timezone-to-date-in-java) better? Also I’d prefer to improve one of the old questions if needed. (I agree that the answer by rzwitserloot here is good.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object is lying. It's not a date. It is a moment in time, and it **has no timezone information**. It's just a wrapper around millis-since-epoch. It physically doesn't have the neccessary fields to store that.

(let's stop calling an instance of j.u.Date a 'date', because it just isn't one. You might as well call all instances of Integer a 'string', and all files 'a Grandma', about as sane). Let's call them by their right name: "crappy instant".

What you've done is **set the timezone of the formatter object**. This is working as intended: When you format this *crappy instant* object with your formatter-with-timezone-info-attached, you get the 'instant in time', translated to human-consumable form, with timezone info, adjusted for that timezone.

Then you ask to parse it back in but that's an issue: that's a very broad job; 'parse this bunch of characters into a "crappy instant"'.

In this case, the bag o' chars you've given includes timezone info already so that will be used. Remember, Date objects **are crappy instants - they contain no timezone!!**

Which should then raise some eyebrows - as last act you log `date`, which effectively logs the result of invoking the `toString()` method on your *crappy instant* instance. This will.... create a formatter with the system default timezone and use that to render it in human form, but make no mistake, that is **NOT** actually what is stored in that *crappy instant* object you have. All that is stored in there is `1600686900000`. That's it.

I strongly suggest you follow deHaar's comment: No, you don't want *crappy instant*. If you have a value handed to you of type *crappy instant* (`java.util.Date`), convert it to `Instant` immediately.

If you must hand off a calculated time value back to some method or interface or field or whatnot and must be in date form, convert your *nice instant* instance (`java.time.Instant`) back to a *crappy instant* form.

Comment: +1, I'll definitely start using the correct name of "crappy instant" for `java.util.Date` in all my explanations of its problems going forward.